# URGENT. Subtle air movements

Tags: logo, movement, design

So, I've been asked to play cleanup man on a sound design of a network logo.

There are a lot of "literal" things going on which have been cut, but I'm going to nix them and ultimately I want to just do some subtle airy movements to transition between segments of it,

I would post a video file for you guys to look at, but ATM it is extremely confidential.

Could anyone direct me in the direction of how I could either create or purchase some nice subliminal futuristic sounds that communicate logo movements and transitions? I know it's a tall order, but I'm sure some of the geniuses which make up our community here could chime in and help a brother out!

Thanks!

-Ryan

Answer (score 2):

What about the new release by Echo collective? 
For example the air movements with the feathers are nicely done.
Check the video at
http://echocollectivefx.com/collections/motion-textures

Otherwise my only suggestion would be to go ahead and record stuff yourself.
But I'm guessing your already near the deadline..

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/index.php/store/cinematic-trailers

Comment: No problem mate. Hope it helped.